# Swift Enum does not conform to protocol CaseIterable

Tags: swift, enums

I want to use `CaseIterable` on an enum just as it is shown in the Swift documentation, but when I do, I always get the error:

> Use of undeclared type CaseIterable

But it should work, as it is shown the same way in the documentation.

```
enum Team: CaseIterable
{
    case team1, team2
}
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Xcode 10 beta 4, which version are you using?

Comment: Is that your exact code, or do you have another case with an *associated value,* like `case team3(name: String)` ?

Comment: @MartinR This is my exact code, and I also get the same error if I copy working code from examples without changing anything.

Comment: Oh well, I think I found my problem... I guess this doesn't work in Xcode 9 does it?

Comment: No, that is a new feature of Swift 4.2. – But Xcode 9 should complain about an undefined protocol `CaseIterable` instead.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, I feel dumb now. I just assumed I had the newest version installed. Well, thanks anyways.

Comment: Why I still can use this in Xcode 10 even when I set the Swift language to 4.0 instead of 4.2?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty simple, just don't use a Xcode version below 10. I am an idiot.

Comment: That does not fully explain it: Xcode 9 would complain about an `undeclared type 'CaseIterable'` and would not add a `typealias AllCases`  ...

Comment: Yeah it does. I added an extension which was supposed to add CaseIterable and forgot about it. Without the extension what you said is the case.

Comment: I'd suggest that you update both question and answer accordingly, so that it makes sense and is possibly helpful for future readers.

Comment: Should I delete the wrong information, or just add a EDIT at the bottom? Sorry for the question

Comment: Delete wrong information. Add all relevant information necessary to make the problem clear and reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

`CaseIterable` is a feature of swift 4.2. Your options are:
1. Download Xcode 10, which comes with this version of swift - [link](https://swift.org/download/#releases)
2. Keep using Xcode 9, and download the Swift 4.2 snapshot - [link](https://developer.apple.com/download/)